# I want to create a button on html but I couldn't adjust to the image

Tags: html, image, button, web

I have a problem because I make buttons but I don't know how I can use it in my web site. The problem is when I import these buttons as images is that I could click just on 1 button instead of 5.
[these are the buttons](http://i62.tinypic.com/f0w0w2.png)

Here you can find the buttons used to make this form https://www.dropbox.com/s/c1iht787jtl5j3s/botones.rar?dl=0

The html code that I used is this :

```
<div style="position: absolute;">
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; z-index: 1;"> <img src="fotos/botones/Boton 1.png"> </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; z-index: 1;"> <img src="fotos/botones/Boton 2.png"> </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; z-index: 1;"> <img src="fotos/botones/Boton 3.png"> </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; z-index: 1;"> <img src="fotos/botones/Boton 4.png"> </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; z-index: 1;"> <img src="fotos/botones/Boton 5.png"> </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you clarify your Question, please? Because  don't really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: At the moment I have 5 images and I want to make each image a button. The problem is that when I try to make it at the end I have the same 1 button for the 5 images so when I click I go everytime to the same page.

Comment: The first one or the last one?

Comment: The last one fill all the the image so i can just use 1 button

Comment: You don't have any buttons, you have divs. If you want buttons, use a `<button>`. It sounds like you just want links though so use `<a>`. Why do you have all that absolute positioning? Why don't you have `alt` attributes?

Comment: The problem that I have when I use <a> is that the last image occup everything so I can't use it because at the end i have only 1 button and i can press everywhere that I will go to the same place . I need to adjust the image to the form of the button but I couldn't I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your style attributes, all the `div`s are on top of each other, so the other ones are there but not visible.

Trying doing something like this:

```
<img id="Image" src="http://oi62.tinypic.com/f0w0w2.jpg" border="0" width="470" height="435" orgWidth="470" orgHeight="435" usemap="#image-map" alt="" />
<map name="image-map" id="ImageMapsCom-image-map">
 <area shape="rect" coords="468,433,470,435" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="Image Map" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_0" />
 <area  alt="" title="" href="/home" shape="poly" coords="14,26,448,26,233,123" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
 <area  alt="" title="" href="/play" shape="poly" coords="126,92,212,281,188,406,13,32" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
 <area  alt="" title="" href="/pending" shape="poly" coords="133,87,230,132,328,91,231,276" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
 <area  alt="" title="" href="/shop" shape="poly" coords="227,283,195,403,258,403" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
 <area  alt="" title="" href="/earn" shape="poly" coords="270,403,448,35,335,92,246,280" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
</map>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/szoszk/L1cepf9w/

moreover you should not use spaces or non-english characters in the `src` attribute

Comment: If I do it like this I can click in the images but at the end I dont have the icon what I want

Comment: So you try to arrange the like on the first link in your question?

Comment: Yes. To make the icon that a want what I do is to overlay the <img> but the problem is if I put the <img> inside the <a> i can just click on the last <img>

Comment: @MiguelRubio I updated it to use a image map. You cna create the easily for example on [http://www.image-maps.com/](http://www.image-maps.com/)

Comment: Thats what I need. Thank you very much